# Create Multiple knockout Grid in one page

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I want to create multiple tables using the KnockOut framework on a single page.

For example, on my page I might need to show four tables bound with knockout with a different `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put more than one different viewmodel in your page I suggest you create a extra viewmodel that holds the viewmodels in observables. That way, you only need to apply the bindings once and you can utilize the **with:** binding on page elements that need to be bound to different viewmodels without the risk of binding multiple times to the same node in the DOM.

Here is a simple example with jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2DD5J/

Comment: There's a problem with the knockout.js included in that fiddle. Updated here: http://jsfiddle.net/2DD5J/14/

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this by adding multiple view models using DIV ids:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(new PagedGridModel(initialData), $("#liveExample")[0]);
        ko.applyBindings(
        ko.applyBindings(new PagedGridModel1(initialData), $("#liveExample1")[0]);
    });

    var initialData = [
                { name: "Well-Travelled Kitten", sales: 352, price: 75.95 },
                { name: "Speedy Coyote", sales: 89, price: 190.00 },
                { name: "Furious Lizard", sales: 152, price: 25.00 },
                { name: "Indifferent Monkey", sales: 1, price: 99.95 },
                { name: "Brooding Dragon", sales: 0, price: 6350 },
                { name: "Ingenious Tadpole", sales: 39450, price: 0.35 },
                { name: "Optimistic Snail", sales: 420, price: 1.50 }
            ];


    var PagedGridModel = function (items) {


        this.items = ko.observableArray(items);

        this.addItem = function () {
        this.items.push({ name: "New item", sales: 0, price: 100 });
        };

        this.sortByName = function () {
            this.items.sort(function (a, b) {
                return a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1;
            });
        };

        this.jumpToFirstPage = function () {
            this.gridViewModel.currentPageIndex(0);
        };

        this.gridViewModel = new ko.simpleGrid.viewModel({
            data: this.items,
            columns: [
        { headerText: "Item Name", rowText: "name" },
        { headerText: "Sales Count", rowText: "sales" },
        { headerText: "Price", rowText: function (item) { return "$" + item.price.toFixed(2) } }
    ],
            pageSize: 4
        });
    };

    var PagedGridModel1 = function (items) {


        this.items = ko.observableArray(items);

        this.addItem = function () {
            this.items.push({ name: "New item", sales: 0, price: 100 });
        };

        this.sortByName = function () {
            this.items.sort(function (a, b) {
                return a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1;
            });
        };

        this.jumpToFirstPage = function () {
            this.gridViewModel1.currentPageIndex(0);
        };

        this.gridViewModel1 = new ko.simpleGrid.viewModel({
            data: this.items,
            columns: [
        { headerText: "Item Name", rowText: "name" },
        { headerText: "Sales Count", rowText: "sales" },
        { headerText: "Price", rowText: function (item) { return "$" + item.price.toFixed(2) } }
    ],
            pageSize: 4
        });
    };
</script>

<div id='liveExample'>
    <div data-bind='simpleGrid: gridViewModel'>
    </div>
    <button data-bind='click: addItem'>
        Add item
    </button>
    <button data-bind='click: sortByName'>
        Sort by name
    </button>
    <button data-bind='click: jumpToFirstPage, enable: gridViewModel.currentPageIndex'>
        Jump to first page
    </button>
</div>
<div id='liveExample1'>
    <div data-bind='simpleGrid: gridViewModel1'>
    </div>
    <button data-bind='click: addItem'>
        Add item
    </button>
    <button data-bind='click: sortByName'>
        Sort by name
    </button>
    <button data-bind='click: jumpToFirstPage, enable: gridViewModel1.currentPageIndex'>
        Jump to first page
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be completed by different approaches depending on your needs:

One view model with four collections or four view models each with one collection.

This is the first one:

```
       function Item(name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        function VM() {
            this.collection1 = ko.observableArray();
            this.collection2 = ko.observableArray();
            this.collection3 = ko.observableArray();

            var self = this;

            self.init = function () {
                var c1i1 = new Item("C1 I1");
                var c1i2 = new Item("C1 I1");

                self.collection1([c1i1, c1i2]);

                var c2i1 = new Item("C2 I1");
                var c2i2 = new Item("C2 I1");

                self.collection2([c2i1, c2i2]);

                var c3i1 = new Item("C3 I1");
                var c3i2 = new Item("C3 I1");

                self.collection3([c3i1, c3i2]);
            };

            self.init();
        }

ko.applyBindings(new VM(), document.getElementById('test'));

     <div id="test">
        <div data-bind="foreach:collection1">
            <div data-bind="text:name"></div>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="foreach:collection2">
            <div data-bind="text:name"></div>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="foreach:collection3">
            <div data-bind="text:name"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

However, if you want to use four different independent view models, you need to create them each with their own collection and apply knockout binding to them by id like:

```
ko.applyBindings(new VM(), document.getElementById('ViewModel1Container'));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QARzK/) with first example.

Answer (score 0):

I made a working example of multiple knockout grids on one page on jsFiddle. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/curtisblackwell/Btyg7/1/) it is.

I'm sure it could be improved upon, but this is what I've got for now.

## HTML

```
<div id="as">
  <h1>As</h1>
  <div data-bind="foreach: as">
    <input name="a1" id="a1" data-bind="value: a1" /><br />
    <input name="a2" id="a2" data-bind="value: a2" /><br />

    <button data-bind="click: removeA">&times;</button><br />
  </div>

  <button data-bind="click: addA">&plus;</button>
</div>

<div id="bs">
  <h1>Bs</h1>
  <div data-bind="foreach: bs">
    <input name="b1" id="b1" data-bind="value: b1" /><br />
    <input name="b2" id="b2" data-bind="value: b2" /><br />

    <button data-bind="click: removeB">&times;</button><br />
  </div>

  <button data-bind="click: addB">&plus;</button>
</div>
```

## JS

```
/* First Grid */
function A(a1, a2) {
  var self = this;

  self.a1 = a1;
  self.a2 = a2;
}

function AsVM() {
  var self = this;

  self.as = ko.observableArray([
    new A('', '')
  ]);

  self.addA = function() {
    self.as.push(new A('', ''));
  }
  self.removeA = function(a) {
    self.as.remove(a);
  }
}

/* Second Grid */
function B(b1, b2) {
  var self = this;

  self.b1 = b1;
  self.b2 = b2;
}

function BsVM() {
  var self = this;

  self.bs = ko.observableArray([
    new B('', '')
  ]);

  self.addB = function() {
    self.bs.push(new B('', ''));
  }
  self.removeB = function(b) {
    self.bs.remove(b);
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(AsVM, document.getElementById('as'));
ko.applyBindings(BsVM, document.getElementById('bs'));
```